# Problems with Executing a DB2 External Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, db2, ibm-midrange

I am trying to call an external stored procedure (calls an RPG program). I keep getting the following error:

> "Exception Details: IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2SQLErrorException: SQL0104 Token @SSN was not valid. Valid tokens: :."

Here is my code:

```
using (iDB2Connection conn = new iDB2Connection(_CONNSTRING))
{
    conn.Open();

    string sqlStatement = "MPRLIB.SIGNTIMESHEET (@SSN, @SIGNATURE, @WORKSTATION, @TOTALHOURS, @COMMENT)";
    //string sqlStatement = "MPRLIB.SIGNTIMESHEET (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    iDB2Command cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = sqlStatement;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SSN", timesheet.EmployeeUniqueKey.ToString("0000000000"));
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SIGNATURE", timesheet.EmployeeTypedName);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@WORKSTATION", timesheet.EmployeeSignedComputer);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TOTALHOURS", GetJobHoursTotal(timesheet.Id).ToString("00000.000").Replace(".", ""));
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@COMMENT", timesheet.EmployeeComments);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

I can't seem to figure out what is happening or why I am getting the above error. My connection string looks like:

```
private const string _CONNSTRING = "DataSource=192.168.50.200;DefaultCollection=QMFILES;Naming=sql;UserID=XXX;Password=XXX;";
```

Could it be a library list issue? The program just references one file that is in the library list. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
using (var conn = new iDB2Connection(_CONNSTRING)) 
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{ 
    conn.Open();

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "MPRLIB.SIGNTIMESHEET";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SSN", timesheet.EmployeeUniqueKey.ToString("0000000000"));
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SIGNATURE", timesheet.EmployeeTypedName);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@WORKSTATION", timesheet.EmployeeSignedComputer);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TOTALHOURS", GetJobHoursTotal(timesheet.Id).ToString("00000.000").Replace(".", ""));
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@COMMENT", timesheet.EmployeeComments);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: The problem was sqlStatement should have excluded the parms. Your post got me in the right direction. Thanks of the help!

Comment: You may also check this post: http://www.netsplore.com/PublicPortal/blog.aspx?EntryID=30

Comment: As a matter to note, you might want to close your connection even if you have wrapped it in a using statement certain versions of the DB2 .NET assembly shipped by IBM did not close connections properly even if enclosed within a using block.